# Div tag, aligning in straight line

Tags: css, html

I have 3 div tags. I have to place it in straight line. in my code it is 2,3,4. 2 and 3 are in straight line but 4 comes downward dono why. I am beginner to html and css. accurately my project is to make a room in perspective view in html. and draw the contents using html canvas.But struck in beginning itself. Experts please help me a way out. I attache my whole project in Jsfiddle and scenario i need solution is written below.

http://jsfiddle.net/kGpdM/855/

```
Html:

<div id="wall">
<div id="sidewall1" align="left">2</div>
<div id="center" align="center">3</div>
<div id="sidewall2" align="right">4</div>
</div>

css:

#sidewall1 {
float:left;
width:250px;
height:500px;
}
#sidewall2 {
float:right;
width:250px;
height:500px;
}
```

Comment: Your JSFiddle doesn't match your description of the problem.

Comment: Sorry i copy pasted the link wrongly sorry. I have edited now. please check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You didn't mentioned the property of ID 'center' so that div itself took a default width.
>   Div 4 comes down because total width (width of id 'row' here 1000px) - width of div 3 = less than 250 px.
>   Also if you are styling through css then try to avoid inline styling use css only.

```
Here is the modified code.

HTML

<div id="container">
    <div id="roof">1</div>
    <div id="wall">
        <div id="sidewall1">2</div>
        <div id="center" >3</div>
        <div id="sidewall2">4</div>
    </div>
    <div id="floor">5</div>
</div>

CSS

body {
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#roof {
padding: 0px;
height: 250px;
width: 1000px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
border-top-width: 0px;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-right-style: solid;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-left-style: solid;
}
#wall {
padding: 0px;
height: 500px;
width: 1000px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
border-top-width: 0px;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-right-style: solid;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-left-style: solid;
}
#floor {
padding: 0px;
height: 250px;
width: 1000px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
border-top-width: 0px;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-right-style: solid;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-left-style: solid;
}
#sidewall1 {
    float:left;
    width:250px;
    height:500px;

}
#sidewall2 {
    float:left;
    width:250px;
    height: 500px;
}
#center {
    float:left;
    width:250px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The style attribute `display:inline;`  adding to all class or iid's u have for the divs 2,3,4 will do.

Comment: check this fiddle out i have just added the display inline attributes to ur div styles   will help..http://jsfiddle.net/kGpdM/851/

Comment: sorry. 2 and 3 is in straight line. But 4 is coming down. I want all in straight line.

Comment: have u checked me fiddle that i have posted it shows all in same line one thing u need to change is to specify percentage value  witdth to div u have declared that wud do..

Answer (score 0):

The width of a computer screen only takes so many pixels. It gets complicated by the fact that there are many different screen widths. For example, you have mobile phones, tablets, laptops, and desktops. But even those can have different widths. So instead of using width: 250px; , it is better to make all those divs in percentages. See below.

```
#sidewall1 {
float:left;
width:25%;
height:500px;
}

#center {
float: left;
width: 49%;
}

#sidewall2 {
float:left;  // Change this to float left
width:25%;
height:500px;
}
```

adjust the percentages according to how you want it.

Comment: You don't need to float everything, it will mess up content below.

Comment: @codehorse, you don't need to set `#center` to 49%...it can be 50%. Just apply `box-sizing: border-box;` to each of the CSS properties.

Comment: I cant get the answer. Can u please elaborate @mike. It will be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `div`s to `inline` may mess up other style. Instead, you should change your CSS, so that the center div is included last. I have added background colors to your CSS to demonstrate:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kGpdM/854/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="wall">
    <div id="sidewall1">2</div>
    <div id="sidewall2">4</div>
    <div id="center">3</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#sidewall1 {
    float:left;
    width:250px;
    height:500px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#center {
    display: block;
    background-color: green;
}
#sidewall2 {
    float:right;
    width:250px;
    height:500px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: sorry. 2 and 3 is in straight line. But 4 is coming down. I want all in straight line.

Comment: Did you look at the fiddle? They ARE in a straight line. The only reason 2 and 4 are taller is because you set a height on them.

Comment: Yes. I saw 2 and 3 are in st. line. but 4 is below 2 and 3. I need it in st. line. my output is 1000*1000 pixel. 2 and 4 with a width of 250 px and height of 500px. and 3 with the width of 500px and height of 500px. I want a separation like this.

Comment: What browser and OS are you using? On a Mac with Chrome, the output of my fiddle (NOT YOUR FIDDLE) looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/89oi6J7.png

Comment: i am using windows with chrome.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot showing the code and the result in one.